# Specify startpoint to interpolate a circle on an arc when clicked on by the user

Tags: javascript, d3.js, interpolation

How do I provide the starting point of an arc for moving a circle along the path of the arc. I have a world map with several arcs displayed on it. I wish to interpolate the movement of a circle on the arc that has been selected by the user using the `.on('click')` event. I wish to know how I can identify the startPoint of the arc in question.

Specifically, I am not able to understand what parameters to provide in `.attr("transform", "translate(" + startPoint + ")")` attribute of the circle to enable the circle to start from the starting position of the arc.

At present, it passes the entire path and I receive the following error

> d3.v3.min.js:1 Error:  attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(M1051.5549785289…".

Although, surprisingly, the circle marker appears on the screen and interpolates along the first arc that has been drawn. However, I wish to change this interpolation to an arc that has been clicked by the user. In other words, how do I feed a new startPoint to the circle marker every time the user clicks on a different arc and to have a subsequent interpolation of the same.

[image]

```
var path3 = arcGroup.selectAll(".arc"),
    startPoint = pathStartPoint(path3)

var marker = arcGroup.append("circle")
marker.attr("r", 7)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + startPoint + ")")

transition();

function pathStartPoint(path) {
  var d = path.attr("d")
  console.log(path)
  dsplitted = d.split(" ");
  return dsplitted[0].split(",");
}

function transition() { 
  marker.transition()
    .duration(7500)
    .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path3.node()))
    .each("end", transition);// infinite loop
}

function translateAlong(path) {
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  return function(i) {
    return function(t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";//Move marker
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you're particular script (or D3, for that matter), works. However, is it possible (or do you already) have a list of markers and their co-ordinates on the screen? It seems to me that you should be able to re-call your arc function whilst passing in those co-ordinates? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Thank you for your response Lewis. The way the arcs are plotted right now is by making use of a LineString wherein I specify three co-ordinates based on which the arcs get drawn. These coordinates are read from a csv file and stored in an array called links. I further make use of links.push followed by a .enter() to plot the arcs

Comment: @sjaikumar There is no need to explicitly set it to a starting point. Once the transition starts running it will call the innermost interpolator function of `translateAlong()` with a starting value of `t = 0`, which will implicitly calculate the starting point.

Comment: Thank you @altocumulus for explaining the theory behind this as well. I was able to implement it now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @altocumulus states in the their comment, `getPointAtLength` doesn't need a starting point.  It takes as an argument a distance from 0 to path length where 0 is the starting point.  Here's a quick example, click on any path below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var w = 400,
      h = 400;

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', w)
      .attr('height', h);

    var data = []
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      data.push({
        x0: Math.random() * w,
        y0: Math.random() * h,
        x1: Math.random() * w,
        y1: Math.random() * h
      });
    }

    var marker = svg.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 20)
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .style("opacity", 0);

    svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.x1 - d.x0,
          dy = d.y1 - d.y0,
          dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + d.x0 + "," + d.y0 + "A" + dr + "," + dr +
          " 0 0,1 " + d.x1 + "," + d.y1;
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d, i) {
        return d3.schemeCategory10[i];
      })
      .style("stroke-width", "10px")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .on("click", function(d){
          marker
            .style("opacity", 1)
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(this))
            .on("end", function(d) {
              marker.style("opacity", 0);
            });
      });

    function translateAlong(path) {
      var l = path.getTotalLength();
      return function(i) {
        return function(t) {
          var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
          return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")"; //Move marker
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you for explaining the theory behind it as well and for your time in in explaining it through an example. I cannot thank you enough :)